# How to make it easier to join a community?

Tags: new-members

I have a Discord server, with just over 3k users. However, we have noticed a slowing down of new members joining, and Discord's server insights state that the server is "**hard to join**".

[image: Discord insights panel]

However:

1. We have always used the native Discord verification system since it was implemented, so I believe verification is easy enough
2. Again, we only use the built-in Discord verification system
3. We don't use 3rd party integrations which restrict or limit access to new users
4. Done.

Is there anything I can do to improve this situation?

**EDIT: The issue somehow corrected itself suddenly. I guess Discord changed how it measures these things? Thanks for everyone who tried to help!**

Comment: Could you Post a Link for joining, so commentators could try this for themselves?

Either way, coming to Community Building for the first time, so largely ignorant, so presumably a fine test subject, I wonder why anyone would want to "join" a server and thus, whether that might be a significant part of why people say your server is "hard to join".

If I'm missing something, I stand to be corrected and to me it seems people might flock to join a community or queue to join a service but hoping anyone might "join a server" sounds perverse.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What moderation setting do you have on your server? (None, Low, Medium, High, Highest. With the verified email and stuff)

Comment: @Ethan Medium I believe

Comment: Is (or was) this question specifically about this Discord feature/warning? Or is it about what might make it hard to join a community in general? This seems like the wrong place for Discord product support (see the second-to-last line of the [on-topic help page](/help/on-topic)); the latter question might be on-topic here, though it may or may not be a bit too broad to be useful.

Answer (score 4):

I have a much smaller server, but our users are usually coming from casual subreddits and not looking to do too much, so even asking them to read the rules is too much.

I'd avoid making authentication with bots (opens a chat that inexperienced users don't see) or having very strict verification rules in your server unless you really need it. Inexperienced users struggle with reaction roles, so ideally you explain it how to do it step-by-step. Yes, mentioning that they have to click/touch a emoji is very useful!

Comment: I have already tried removing authentication with bots, I mention only using the discord built in verification system (easy to use popup with check box). It hasn't seemed to work

Comment: I know you posted this on March, did it not change since then? Discord is a bit harsh with this metric, even 20% is considered bad for them. I wouldn't worry too much about it if participation in your server by new users is still happening.

Comment: it has jumped around 20-30% a lot (now its ~20%) but yes, someone new users occasionally do pop in and have a chat (and those who do often stay around).

Comment: Just an update, which is more related to Reddit than Discord. Reddit recently launched Reddit Talk, and we use it to have casual voice chat on it. Some people, I've learned, simply don't like or understand Discord interface. So we have these chats and invite users to continue the convo there. Our Week 1 retention went from ~20% to almost 40%.